# Merging list of multi-index series in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm working with thousands of `pd.series` each with a multi-index that has 2 static index, a dynamic one, and then timestamps:

```
start = np.concatenate((np.random.rand(3), [np.nan]*3))
end = np.concatenate(([np.nan]*3, np.random.rand(3)))

index1 = pd.MultiIndex(levels = [["X"], ["Y"], ["A"], ["d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6"]],
                       labels = [[0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,2,3,4,5]],
                       names = ["static1", "static2", "dynamo", "timestamps"])
i1_start = pd.Series(start, index=index1, name="col1")
i1_end = pd.Series(end, index=index1, name="col2")

index2 = index1 = pd.MultiIndex(levels = [["X"], ["Y"], ["B"], ["d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6"]],
                       labels = [[0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,2,3,4,5]],
                       names = ["static1", "static2", "dynamo", "timestamps"])
i2_start = pd.Series(start, index=index2, name="col1")
i2_end = pd.Series(end, index=index2, name="col2")

data = [i1_start, i1_end, i2_start, i2_end]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df
```

Here are the results of turning it into a dataframe:

```
                                    col1    col2    col1    col2
static1 static2 dynamo  timestamps              
X           Y      A          d1    0.248504    NaN NaN NaN
                              d2    0.424774    NaN NaN NaN
                              d3    0.333638    NaN NaN NaN
                              d4    NaN 0.987744    NaN NaN
                              d5    NaN 0.093231    NaN NaN
                              d6    NaN 0.918666    NaN NaN
                    B         d1    NaN NaN 0.248504    NaN
                              d2    NaN NaN 0.424774    NaN
                              d3    NaN NaN 0.333638    NaN
                              d4    NaN NaN NaN 0.987744
                              d5    NaN NaN NaN 0.093231
                              d6    NaN NaN NaN 0.918666
```

I'm looking for advice on how to groupby the series with the same `series.names` and `concat/merge/join` them so that the columns line up, instead of having an entire triangle of just null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) or [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) and parameter `axis=1` with `level=0`:

```
data = [i1_start, i1_end, i2_start, i2_end]
df = pd.concat(data, 1).sum(axis=1, level=0)
#same as
#df = pd.concat(data, 1).groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()

#alternative 
df = pd.concat(data, 1).max(axis=1, level=0)

print (df)
                                       col1      col2
static1 static2 dynamo timestamps                    
X       Y       A      d1          0.771148       NaN
                       d2          0.074757       NaN
                       d3          0.526310       NaN
                       d4               NaN  0.975088
                       d5               NaN  0.992226
                       d6               NaN  0.465135
                B      d1          0.771148       NaN
                       d2          0.074757       NaN
                       d3          0.526310       NaN
                       d4               NaN  0.975088
                       d5               NaN  0.992226
                       d6               NaN  0.465135
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think to use `sum` for combining columns.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df.fillna(0).sum(1)
```

That is, replace NaN with zero and sum all the columns for each row.

Comment: I'm sorry I should of been clearer and pointed out that I needed to keep the column names.